# Export the WPF Window data to HTML or any other printable format

Tags: c#, wpf

C# WPF windows application screen has multiple grids and textboxs, now I need to show all the content of the page into printable format, then print, here each grid is having more then some 500 records, I have to print all the data, before print I have to show in printable view of all data.

Is any open source already available for this?

Or any other approach to achieve this?

Or is any way to export the data to HTML format?

Comment: What about a FlowDocument?

Comment: I think you will have to compose printable version of your data from scratch. FlowDocument is one of possible formats for this.

Answer (score 0):

The code below lets you get an image of FrameworkElement(your window):
You can use the image and print the image:
(I am not sure what the image will look like as you have more than 500 records though)

> ```
>       Transform transform = element.LayoutTransform;
>         element.LayoutTransform = null;
> ```

```
        double width = element.ActualWidth;
        double height = element.ActualHeight;

        // fix margin offset as well
        Thickness margin = element.Margin;
        element.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, margin.Right - margin.Left, margin.Bottom - margin.Top);

        // Get the size of canvas
        Size size = new Size(width, height);

        // force control to Update
        element.Measure(size);
        element.Arrange(new Rect(size));

        RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)width, (int)height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

        bmp.Render(element);

        // return values as they were before
        element.LayoutTransform = transform;
        element.Margin = margin;
        Clipboard.SetImage(bmpCopied);
```